# How can I prevent a gitlab job running on push event

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a simple gitlab-yaml file that I thought would run a job when only scheduled. However, it is getting fire on a push event as well.
Can anyone please tell me the correct way in which to specify that a job is only run when scheduled.
This is my gitlab-yaml file

```
job:on-schedule:
    only:
        - schedules
        - branches
    script:
        - /usr/local/bin/phpunit -c phpunit_config.xml
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the GitLab documentation, `branches` means "When a branch is pushed".

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#only-and-except-simplified

So including `branches` in your `only:` section causes the pipeline job to also run on pushes to any branch.

You can either remove the `branches` entry, or if you wanted to restrict to pushes for a specific branch you could extend the branch entry to include project and branch name (`branches@<project>/<branch>`).

My suggestion is to reduce your YML to:

```
job:on-schedule:
    only:
        - schedules
    script:
        - /usr/local/bin/phpunit -c phpunit_config.xml
```

Comment: Yes. In `only` option you can only use either branch name as a regex or use `branches` keyword.